# how to generate the instance for logger?

Tags: java, logging

Here is my code

```
package com.my;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Log {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
           FileHandler hand = new FileHandler("vk.log");
           Logger log = Logger.getLogger("log_file");
           log.addHandler(hand);
           log.warning("Doing carefully!");
           log.info("Doing something ...");
           log.severe("Doing strictily ");
           System.out.println(log.getName());
      }
      catch(IOException e){
           System.out.println(e)
      }
    }
```

}

Comment: What's your question? Also, please remove the empty catch block, since it'll swallow any exceptions and you won't understand what's going on. Replace it with `catch(IOException e){ throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work if you delete the superfluous `log.getLogger("");` statement and fix the imports.

A couple of comments:

- If you have multiple loggers you can selectively turn them on and off.  It is conventional to create multiple loggers based on class or package names; e.g.

  ```
  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
  ```

  or

  ```
  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
  ```
- You are instantiating and associating the handler programmatically.  It is a better idea to put the logging configurations into an XML or properties file, and use one of the configurers to load it and wire up the logging handlers.  This allows you ... or the user ... to adjust the logging without modifying your code.
- You should probably READ the [log4j introduction](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) document that explains the above and other things about using log4j.

---

The above assumes that you were trying to use `log4j`.  Is you are really trying to use `java.util.logging`, some details are not exactly right.  (And, IMO, you *would be better off* with using `log4j` or one of its offspring.)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: log is instance for my class?

Comment: Of course not.  Your class is named `Log`, and the `log` variable (that I borrowed from your code!) has type `Logger`.

Comment: careful with the use of SomeClass.class, the OP is using java.util.logging and not Log4j, so the class argument is not accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more or less fine (check the imports) and should work correctly if you remove the line:

```
log.getLogger("");
```

A working implementation of your class would then be:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileHandler hand = new FileHandler("vk.log");
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("log_file");
        log.addHandler(hand);
        log.warning("Doing carefully!");
        log.info("Doing something ...");
        log.severe("Doing strictily ");
        System.out.println(log.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle error.
    }
}
```

}

Can you explain further your problem?

Comment: is log is instance of my class?

Comment: No, log is an instance of the Logger.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple suggestions.

- Watch your imports, you are mixing
  Log4j or java.util.logging imports
- no need to call getLogger() twice
- Do something with your exceptions,
  even if that means using a
  <strike>System.out.println()</strike> e.printStackTrace() in this test
  case. If there were problems thrown,
  you were hiding them.

Comment: yeah e.printStackTrace() would be the preferred